# How to emulate right click options by Capybara?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, ruby, capybara

I want to be stand on a specific element in the page then I make right click and choose one option from the menu appears

Comment: https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FElement:right_click

Answer (score 2):

If it's the system right click menu then you can't.  If it's a page generated right click menu then you just interact like any other element on the page.